# Color change for tkitner button giving confusing outputs

Tags: python, button, user-interface, tkinter

I have asked this question before with no successful answers so I will try again.

Below is code that (should) change the background colour of a button when pressed.  It basically takes the number 'eleNum' and then uses that to print out 4 'panels' of buttons ranging 0 to 40.

Here is the strange bit. The panel number 4 works as intended but the rest of them just give me an error. For instance if I press a button in panel 2:

```
line 113, in chooser
   self.Buttons2[index].onfigure(bg="orange")
AttributreError: 'int' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

Here is my code.

```
def floorChooserButtons( self, eleNum, floors, yStart, yEnd, xStart, xEnd):
    self.Buttons1 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.Buttons2 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.Buttons3 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.Buttons4 = [i for i in range(41)]
    self.eleNumber = [i for i in range(4)]
    if(eleNum is 1):
        self.eleNumber[0] = tk.Label(self, width = 12, text="Elevator 1")
        self.eleNumber[0].grid(row = xStart-1, column =yStart+1, columnspan=3)
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart 
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons1[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons1[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
    elif(eleNum is 2):
        self.eleNumber[1] = tk.Label(self, width = 12, text="Elevator 2")
        self.eleNumber[1].grid(row = xStart-1, column =yStart+1, columnspan=3)
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons2[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons2[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
    elif(eleNum is 3):
        self.eleNumber[2] = tk.Label(self, width = 12, text="Elevator 3")
        self.eleNumber[2].grid(row = xStart-1, column =yStart+1, columnspan=3)
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons3[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons3[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
    elif(eleNum is 4):
        self.eleNumber[3] = tk.Label(self, width = 12, text="Elevator 4")
        self.eleNumber[3].grid(row = xStart-1, column =yStart+1, columnspan=3)
        xPos = xStart
        yPos = yStart
        for floor in floors:
            if(yPos == yEnd):
                xPos = xPos + 1
                yPos = yStart
            if(xPos == xEnd-1):
                yPos = yStart+2
            self.Buttons4[floor] = tk.Button(self, width=3, text=floor, 
                command = lambda f=floor: self.chooser(f, eleNum))
            self.Buttons4[floor].grid(row=xPos, column =yPos)
            yPos = yPos + 1
        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
            command=root.destroy).grid(row = xPos, column = yPos)


def chooser(self, index, eleNum):
    print("Number", index, "pressed in elevator", eleNum)
    if eleNum is 1:
        self.Buttons1[index].configure(bg="blue")
    if eleNum is 2:
        self.Buttons2[index].configure(bg="orange")
    if eleNum is 3:
        self.Buttons3[index].configure(bg="pink")
    if eleNum is 4:
        self.Buttons4[index].configure(bg="red")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have integers in your lists. You put them there yourself, e.g.: `self.Buttons2 = [i for i in range(41)]`. After this, you change only some of them to buttons, e.g.: `self.Buttons2[floor] = tk.Button( ...`.

Then you try to call the `configure` method on an integer - the error message explains this quite directly. Obviously integers don't have a `configure` method.

So your code will work always for only one panel. After you call `floorChooserButtons` with given `eleNum` all lists are being reset to integers, and only the one corresponding to `eleNum` is being filled with buttons (still, only for indices within the `floors` list).

A quick fix is to move the part:

```
self.Buttons1 = [i for i in range(41)]
self.Buttons2 = [i for i in range(41)]
self.Buttons3 = [i for i in range(41)]
self.Buttons4 = [i for i in range(41)]
```

to the constructor. Then, after calling `floorChooserButtons` for all panels you will fill them with actual buttons, not numbers. Your whole construction still doesn't make sense to me though (why would you have integers in lists with intention to store buttons in them?).

As a side note, you use the `is` operator incorrectly. It works here accidentally, because integers in Python are immutable, but it's not very readable. For value-equality testing you should use the `==` operator.